# How to bypass Available authorizations dialog in Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, swagger, swagger-ui, claims-based-identity

Swagger UI has a swagger-oauth.js which displays an "Available authorizations" dialog for selecting the scope(s). The available scopes are defined in code via AddSecurityDefinition.

However, I would like to bypass this dialog and have the scopes automatically selected. Could anyone advise how to do this or even provide the necessary code\config?

Thanks heaps!

Comment: What's the use case? Authorize "try it out" requests automatically, without user interaction?

Comment: I still want the login screen to appear, just not the "Available authorizations" dialog prior to the login screen

Comment: Hi @Helen any thoughts?

Comment: No idea, sorry.